# 'app-bemvindo' is not a known element Angular 2+

Tags: angular, componentes, programação-estruturada

Meus componentes estão organizados da seguinte maneira:

## app.module

```
src/
App.Module.ts: Importa os módulos dos componentes <br>
App.Routing.module.ts: Rotas raiz do sistema
```

## bemvindo.module

```
src/app/components/ <br>
bemvindo -> <br>
bemvindo.module.ts (Aqui eu importo o meu componente) <br>
bemvindo.routing.module.ts (Aqui estão as rotas deste componente)<br>
bemvindo.component.ts <br>
bemvindo.component.html<br>
```

## dashboard.module

```
dashboard.module.ts (Aqui eu importo o meu componente) <br>
dashboard.routing.module.ts (Aqui estão as rotas deste componente)<br>
dashboard.component.ts <br>
dashboard.component.html
```

O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo utilizar o componente app-bemvindo dentro do componente app-dashboard.

Obs: Estou importando ambos os módulos no meu `app.module.ts`.

Já tentei exportar tanto o componente quanto o módulo no meu `app-bemvindo.module` e importar na `dashboard.module`, mas mesmo assim não reconhece.

O que tem de errado com minha estrutura?

Answer (score 1):

Para usar o componente de um module dentro de outro module vc tem que adicionar ele aos exports.

```
declarations: [MeuComponent],
exports: [MeuComponent]
```